# onclick passing self sending too many elements

Tags: javascript

I created the following p element in a for loop. When this particular element is clicked, I want the single element to be passed to the method below, however this is not the case. The whole array of elements are passed. Can someone help?

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
          var stuff= document.createElement("p");
          stuff.onclick = methodA(stuff);
 }

function methodA(self){

   var id = self.id;
   var myemail= id;

}
```

I tried

```
stuff.onclick = methodA(this);
```

and it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

You are actually calling the method `methodA` and assigning the result of that call to `onclick`.  Instead I believe your intention is to create a closure so that `methodA` is called at the time of the click.  Like so:

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
  var stuff = document.createElement("p");
  stuff.appendChild(document.createTextNode("p #" + i));
  
  // Using a closure
  stuff.onclick = (function(cStuff){ return function() { methodA(cStuff); } })(stuff);

  // Or instead you could use 'bind'
  // stuff.onclick = methodA.bind(null, stuff);
  
  document.body.appendChild(stuff);
}

function methodA(self) {

  var id = self.id;
  var myemail = id;

}
```

Comment: i don't see any closure, you should wrap the function with `(function(cStuff){ ... })(stuff)`

Comment: Thanks @Hacketo, fixed this to be a proper closure.